# best way to change the date format in mysql SELECT?

Tags: mysql

Can any one please let me know, i need to change the data format `2010-05-14 17:53` to `14/05/2010 17:53` using mysql select query

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this select..

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i") FROM <TableName> WHERE <clause>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select date_format(date_column, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i") from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link might help you
[MySQL Manuel](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

This should do the trick :

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

For hour, u can use %H or %h, depending if you want 24h or 12h display.
%H will set 24h, %h will set 12h.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` to format your DATE. To solve your conversion, use the following code as a pointer

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2010-05-14 17:53', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

Comment: when i use this query a ` sign automatically coming with query so error reported